# Is there a way to substitute operators depending on a condition?

Tags: ruby

I have an if/else condition, and the if and else sections are identical, save for the operator used. In one case `<`, and in the other `>`. Is there a way to conditionally set that operator, to DRY out the code?

```
if count_year < end_year
    while count_year <= end_year
        if count_year % 4 == 0
            if count_year % 100 != 0
                all_years << count_year unless (count_year % 400 == 0)
            end
        end
        count_year += 1
    end
    puts all_years
elsif count_year > end_year
    while count_year >= end_year
        if count_year % 4 == 0
            if count_year % 100 != 0
                all_years << count_year unless (count_year % 400 == 0)
            end
        end
        count_year -= 1
    end
    puts all_years.reverse
end
```

This is part of a program for printing out leap years between two given years. I feel like there must be a way to not have to repeat the loop twice. Something like: `count_year < end_year ? operator = "<" : operator = ">"` - Then using that variable to substitute the operator into a code block or something? Any ideas?

Comment: Well, your `if`/`else` blocks are **not** identical: http://diffchecker.com/95tE8044

Comment: Thanks @sawa. It was not really obvious :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one small improvement, you can extract really identical parts into a method. Then duplication stops being so massive.

```
# I'm too lazy to come up with a proper name for it.
def foo count_year, all_years
  if count_year % 4 == 0
    if count_year % 100 != 0
      all_years << count_year unless (count_year % 400 == 0)
    end
  end
end


# later...

if count_year < end_year
  while count_year <= end_year
    foo count_year, all_years
    count_year += 1
  end
  puts all_years
elsif count_year > end_year
  while count_year >= end_year
    foo count_year, all_years
    count_year -= 1
  end
  puts all_years.reverse
end
```

### But, the operator substitution...

Yes, there is a way to dynamically choose an operator for evaluation. You see, operators in ruby are just method calls, nothing more. These two lines are equivalent:

```
7 > 5
7.>(5)
```

And here's a snippet that chooses random operator for comparison. I leave it up to you to adapt it for your problem (if you want, that is. I advise you against this).

```
def is_7_greater_than_5
  operator = [:<, :>].sample # pick random operator
  7.send(operator, 5)
end

is_7_greater_than_5 # => false
is_7_greater_than_5 # => false
is_7_greater_than_5 # => true
is_7_greater_than_5 # => true
is_7_greater_than_5 # => true
```

Comment: Okay I see where you're coming from. Answer is a bit scrappy, but that's because my approach is a bit scrappy. I'm accepting this one because it's more relevant, even though I'll probably use DigitalRoss's approach. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def example count_year, end_year
  all_years = []

  dir, test = count_year < end_year                      ?
    [ 1, proc { |c, e| c <= e }] : count_year > end_year ?
    [-1, proc { |c, e| c >  e }] :
    [ 0, proc { |c, e| false  }]

  while test.call count_year, end_year
    if count_year % 4 == 0
      if count_year % 100 != 0
        all_years << count_year unless count_year % 400 == 0
      end
    end
    count_year += dir
    puts dir > 0 ? all_years : all_years.reverse
  end
end
```

Comment: I love it. Proc is still a little confusing to me so I never thought of using it, but this is super succinct and I'll be going out of my way to study up on Proc more to do things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Aww. Why did you do a code golf exercise and accept an answer so quickly? Boo! :( hehe. just kidding. The early bird gets the worm. I perhaps took the problem too literally as I think you're just looking to experiment with compare.

I would use the built in functions of ruby and decomposed this method into a class. :)

```
require 'date'

class LeapYearFinder

  attr_reader :years, :years_reversed

  def initialize(start_year, end_year)
    @start_year    = Date.parse("1/1/#{start_year.to_s}")
    @end_year      = Date.parse("1/1/#{end_year.to_s}")
    @years         ||= leap_years
  end

  def compare_range
    @compare_range ||= Range.new(@start_year, @end_year)
  end

  def leap_years
    years = []
    compare_range.step {|x| years << x.year if x.leap? }
    years.uniq!
  end

  def years_reversed
    @years.reverse
  end

end

lp = LeapYearFinder.new(1900, 2012)

puts "Years putzed"
lp.years.map {|x| puts x}

puts "Years reversed"
lp.years_reversed.map {|x| puts x}
```

#### Some corner case issues

- handle a reverse date input
- step properly through the range thus avoiding the *uniq!* and maybe yielding better performance